# Make my git user and apache user have read/write/delete access

Tags: centos, permissions, file-permissions

I am having permission problems on my server. I use user developer to pull my git repository on the server. Then apache uses its own apache user to do write and execute code. I always have the problems when the app wants to write something in the directory (i.e: log files, and cache ...) if I execute a cron job and it uses my developer rights and wants to add something to the folders that is written by apache.

My question is how to have my developer have the same write/delete access as my apache and avoid permission conflicts with each other? I am not fluent on linux command so, it would help if you could provide links or simply examples of doing so.

thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My idea was to make the following ownership of the directory:
developer.app
or
apache.app

In Bash:

```
ROOT=/some/directory/app
chown -R developer.app $ROOT
```

or

```
chown -R apache.app $ROOT
```

In the first case its necessary to have "apache" in "app" group, in the second to have "developer" in "app". Then you need to set the same permissions for both: owner and group on all files/directories. How to do it depends on infrastructure you use. It can be grepping /etc/passwd looking after the second number, and /etc/group for group names. If you use centrify or other software that connects Linux to centralized account database, you probably need to su to a particular account and issue `id`.

My simplified rule of thumb is to make all files `rw-` and scripts in hooks directory `rwx`, but your code probably needs more granularity. Its good practice to avoid 777 permissions.

```
find $ROOT -type f -exec chmod 0660 {} \;
find $ROOT -type d -exec chmod 0770 {} \;
find $ROOT/.git/hooks -type f -exec chmod 0770 {} \;
```

You may prefer to use `ug+rw` or `ug+rwx` what only adds missing permissions. Probably better if you have already some specific `eXec` permissions on some files.

To automatically make new files and directories readable/writeable for both, please set umask to 0007.